# When to call "setFdOption fd CloseOnExec True"?

Tags: sockets, haskell

I found this when reading the [warp source code](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-2.19/warp-3.0.13.1/src/Network-Wai-Handler-Warp-Run.html#runSettings).

```
-- | Run an 'Application' with the given 'Settings'.
runSettings :: Settings -> Application -> IO ()
runSettings set app = withSocketsDo $
    bracket
        (bindPortTCP (settingsPort set) (settingsHost set))
        sClose
        (\socket -> do
            setSocketCloseOnExec socket
            runSettingsSocket set socket app)

-- Copied from: https://github.com/mzero/plush/blob/master/src/Plush/Server/Warp.hs
setSocketCloseOnExec :: Socket -> IO ()
#if WINDOWS
setSocketCloseOnExec _ = return ()
#else
setSocketCloseOnExec socket =
    setFdOption (fromIntegral $ fdSocket socket) CloseOnExec True
#endif
```

> Sockets used by the web server need to be set so that they are not leaked into processes fork/exec'd by the shell.

However, [`acceptFork`](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-2.19/network-simple-0.4.0.4/src/Network-Simple-TCP.html#acceptFork) in `Network.Simple.TCP` module does not set `CloseOnExec` option. Shouldn't this option be the default?

Comment: There is a discussion going right now about this in the [haskell-cafe mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/haskell-cafe/sFr3OqFg9g0)

Comment: This discussion on Google Groups is inaccessible.